# Draw in QGLFrameBufferObject

Tags: qt, opengl

With Qt and opengl, I would like draw in a QGlFrameBufferObject ? 
I try this :

```
QGLFrameBufferObject * fbo = new QGLFramebufferObject(200, 200, QGLFramebufferObject::NoAttachment, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA32F);  
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0f, fbo->size().width(), fbo->size().height(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
fbo->bind();
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
fbo->release();
fbo->toImage().save("test.jpg"));
```

But I don't get a red image.

**OTHER QUESTION**

And if I want draw with :

```
glBegin(GL_QUAD); 
glColor3d(0.2, 0.5, 1.0); 
glVertex2i( 10, 20);
glColor3d(0.7, 0.5, 1.0); 
glVertex2i( 15, 20);
glColor3d(0.8, 0.4, 1.0); 
glVertex2i( 15, 25);
glColor3d(0.1, 0.9, 1.0); 
glVertex2i( 10, 25);
glEnd();
```

Do I need also `glClear()` ?

Comment: Can you try a format like `GL_RGBA8` instead? `GL_RGBA32F` *should* work, but it's a much more recent and more rarely used format. To narrow down the problem, it would be worth checking if a more basic format works.

Comment: I have the same problem with `GL_RGBA8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually clear the framebuffer. `glClearColor()` only sets the color used for clearing, but does not clear anything. You will need to add the second line here:

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The `glClear()` call will clear the color buffer with the clear color you specified in the first call. The framebuffer content is initially undefined, so you should always clear the framebuffer with a `glClear()` call before you start drawing. The only exception is if you're certain that the primitives you render will cover every pixel of the drawing surface. Even then, on some architectures it can actually be better for performance to still call `glClear()` first.

It shouldn't matter yet as long as you only clear the buffer. But once you want to start drawing, you will also need to set the viewport:

```
glViewport(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

Comment: Please don't edit questions to turn them into something different. The intention of this site is to build a repository of questions and answers. If the questions are edited, the answers won't match the questions anymore.

Comment: Ok, I extended the answer.