# Unable to clear OpenGL viewport

Tags: python-2.7, opengl, pyopengl

I copied [this script (pasted below)](http://winfred-lu.blogspot.ch/2012/09/writing-your-first-pyqt4-opengl-program.html) and ran it. Unfortunately, the image appears scrambled, as below. Can anyone help me get rid of that?

**Config:**

- Ubuntu 13.10
- Pyopengl 3.0.1b1
- graphic card AMD Radeon HD 6650M
- OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.0-devel (git-32c5544 saucy-oibaf-ppa)

  ```
  from OpenGL.GL import *
  from PyQt4 import QtGui
  from PyQt4.QtOpenGL import *

      class WfWidget(QGLWidget):
          def __init__(self, parent = None):
              super(WfWidget, self).__init__(parent)

          def paintGL(self):
              glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
              glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
              glRectf(-5, -5, 5, 5)
              glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
              glBegin(GL_LINES)
              glVertex3f(0, 0, 0)
              glVertex3f(20, 20, 0)
              glEnd()

          def resizeGL(self, w, h):
              glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
              glLoadIdentity()
              glOrtho(-50, 50, -50, 50, -50.0, 50.0)
              glViewport(0, 0, w, h)

          def initializeGL(self):
              glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
              glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      app = QtGui.QApplication(["Winfred's PyQt OpenGL"])
      widget = WfWidget()
      widget.show()
      app.exec_()
  ```

[image]

Comment: Different language, but otherwise this is pretty much the same as this one from a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567993/draw-in-qglframebufferobject/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move, `glClear` to the `paint` method:

```
def paintGL(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glRectf(-5, -5, 5, 5)
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0)
    glVertex3f(20, 20, 0)
    glEnd()
```

Also here:

```
    def initializeGL(self):
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

you don't need `glClear` here.
Produces:

[image]

Comment: You'll probably want the `glClear()` call after `glClearColor()`, though. Or simply not have the `glClearColor()` call in `paintGL()`, since having it in `initializeGL()` is enough. Calling it after `glClear()` does not serve any useful purpose.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: O yeah, missed that... Thanks!

Comment: funnily, came here googling for possible reasons of this happening on Linux: 1) you set up everything properly 2) you clear 3) you don't draw anything after (except for a flush or finish) 4) you swap buffers -- and nothing gets cleared [drawing just anything makes clear happen, too] Point is: there might be also be bugs in GL implementations / drivers that lead to this :)