# open gl basic program error?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>

void display (void)
{
    glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("Colorcube Viewer");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

i am not able to figure out whats the problem with this code ?
it does not give me a red window.

Comment: After setting the clear color, you need call the clear command `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`.

Comment: yes thanks . can you tell me why sometimes it gives me a transparent window

Comment: I dont know all the unexpected behavior the `glFLush()` can have in your example, so I dont know why it is transparent anytime. In your small example, you dont need `glEnd` and `glFlush`, though.

Comment: You should remove that `glEnd()` there, you don't have any primitive started with `glBegin()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw in QGLFrameBufferObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567993/draw-in-qglframebufferobject)

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` after setting the clear color (because you have depth test enabled, make sure that you're clearing both the color buffer AND the depth buffer

Comment: Glad to hear it! Don't forget to accept the answer to indicate that it worked